# Jenkins Github oAuth 404 error in callback

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i am trying to use Jenkins' Github oAuth plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+OAuth+Plugin)

```
Name: Name of app
URL: http://server:8080
Cacllback: http://server:8080/securityRealm/finishLogin
```

When i enable Github oAuth, it did pop up to say whether I want to allow this Appliation from Github, then I click Allow.

So the authenticate step went through, but I hit 404 because **The requested resource (/securityRealm/finishLogin) is not available.**

There is nothing in Tomcat manager that says securityRealm, is there something else I need to set up to use this plugin?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have jenkins served at server:port then the callback will not be present.  More than likely you are serving from server:port/jenkins because you are using tomcat and this is what is specified in the web.xml for the jenkins war.

The callback location for your server is going to be

```
server:port/jenkins/securityRealm/finishLogin
```

if you are using a Servlet container like tomcat or jetty.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have the plugin correctly configured in your settings.
After entering the Client ID and Client Secret you get from github and restarting Jenkins it should work.
I ran into the same problem and this worked for me.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what the correct settings are?

Answer (score 1):

When I was in the process of setting up the OAUTH plugin, I found it handy to check the `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` file for correct settings:

```
<securityRealm class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubSecurityRealm">
  <githubWebUri>https://github.com</githubWebUri>
  <githubApiUri>https://api.github.com</githubApiUri>
  <clientID>3d404d2blah42ruSerious27</clientID>
  <clientSecret>{AQAwZXfnxuJQxEL9iEEXuXPmW5BdeadBeefBreDactedJMcw==}</clientSecret>
  <oauthScopes>read:org,user:email</oauthScopes>
</securityRealm>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is you need to have a Security Realm set beforehand for the route to be available. I did the following steps to get it working:

1. Install Github Oauth plugin (restarted Jenkins for good measure)
2. Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security
3. Tick Enable Security and choose Github Authentication Plugin
4. Under "Authorization", make sure "Anyone can do anything" and click Save at the bottom. (Previously, I filled in all of the settings and hit save, however I was still receiving a 404 and locked myself out).

At this point, I tried to hit http://:8080/securityRealm/finishLogin and it responded with a HTTP/1.1 302 Found.

After I confirmed I was not receiving a 404 any longer for the resource, I went back into "Configure Global Security" and setup the rest of the plugin with the Client ID and Client Secret, selected "Github Commiter Authorization Strategy" for Authorization, added my username, saved and now able to auth via Github.

Hope this helps.

Jenkins Version: version 1.558
Github Auth plugin: version 0.14